# How to check whether the date is in the future?

Tags: jinja2

I need to display the information if the date given is in the future. Is there a way to do this in a template?

I found out I should compare them as timestamps but the following code gives me "jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'as_timestamp' is undefined".

```
{% if as_timestamp(bibjson.discontinued_date) <=  as_timestamp(time.today) %}
  <p>This date should be displayed only if in the past: {{ date.strftime("%d %B %Y") }}</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: As long as you are passing a `datetime` class in a variable `datetime`, that should do, yes

Comment: I don't, I am looking for a way without passing the additional variables in the template.

Comment: Then, no. There is no date/datetime concept in Jinja.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very easy with custom filter https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/custom-template-tags/

The filter file:

```
import datetime

from django.template import Library

register = Library()


@register.filter('date_in_the_past')
def date_in_the_past(date):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    return date <= now
```

and in the template:

```
{% load filter %}
{% if bibjson.discontinued_date|date_in_the_past %}
    <p>This date should be displayed only if in the past: {{ bibjson.discontinued_date|date:'d F Y' }}</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you! I work with Flask, but I believe this will be similar.